# Android Location listener is not working

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I would like to get current device location and open `Google Maps` with this:

```
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);


    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }




private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&daddr=55.877526, 26.533898"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

But this code is not working: for some reasons listener is ignored.

Why and how to fix it ?

Comment: Why are you instantiating location listener as `LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();` and not as `MyLocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();`

Answer (score 2):

> "Why..."

Because `requestLocationUpdates()` is an asynchorous operation and the result (the location) is returned in the `onLocationChanged()` callback. The location isn't available immediately.

> "...and how to fix it ?"

Move your Google map intent code there:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

    longitude = loc.getLongitude();
    latitude = loc.getLatitude();

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&daddr=55.877526, 26.533898"));
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: My understanding is that you'll also want to unregister your location listener to avoid leaking the activity - see the [`removeUpdates`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates(android.location.LocationListener)) method.

Comment: @Markus I changed and problem still here, I have tried to debug this and it seems that onLocationChanged() is not called..

Comment: It can take some time for the location to be obtained. The refresh period interval you set, 5,000 milliseconds in your case, is the _minimum_ period between refreshes. It can be longer for several reasons. You're also specifying a minimum distance of 10 metres, so any location changes which result in the location moving less than 10 metres from where it was previously won't be returned to you. Consider setting this to 0, at least initially.

Comment: If you are indoors then GPS just might not work no matter how long you wait. Just to test your code you can also request network based locations with `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);
`