# LocationListener not fetching current location of user

Tags: java, android, location, locationmanager

I'm trying to get user's current location using LocationManager and LocationListener. But not getting any value.

Below is code I'm using in Java:

```
  // activity is implementing LocationListener
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  // in onCreate() method.

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      requestLocationPermission();
      return;
    }
    else {
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    //outside onCreate()
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double longitude =  location.getLongitude();
        double latitude =  location.getLatitude();
        NavProfileLocation.setText(String.valueOf(longitude)+" AND "+String.valueOf(latitude));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(longitude)+" AND "+String.valueOf(latitude),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I want to fetch latitude and longitude using GPS of the current user.

Comment: is there any error in logs?
did you check the permissions?

Comment: yes, I check that. all permissions are granted already by the user.

Comment: What is your exact problem? is onLocationChanged called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Location listener is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576882/android-location-listener-is-not-working)

Comment: @RajatMehra no. not called. that's the main problem

Comment: @GulshanYadav and no error in logs?

Comment: @RajatMehra no not getting anything

Comment: @GulshanYadav Are you inside building ?  GPS won't work indoor. You can use Network provider for indoor.

Comment: tried that too. but i'm using tablet to test app. not working in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Last update from android doc api : 
Check network and location providers.

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;

// ..

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
}



fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                if (location != null) {
                    // Logic to handle location object
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: i'm using minSDK 16 and targetSDK 28

Comment: OK , for now just try to combine some little variant with version : compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1". Try some other version in this line ...Also provide in manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: Good , target28 is nice keep always if it possible to the higher version number.